# Resizing/responsive thumbnails in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just learning how to create responsive websites with Bootstrap in Dreamweaver CC 2015.
Following Adobe's tutorials, I've added 4 Bootstrap Thumbnail elements across the page in a row. 
Problem is that at about 991px, they resize to 4 large images & fill up the space.
I'd like them to resize to "two-up & two-down" at 991px & be responsive down to mobile phone size where they can be 100% across the screen.
Do I use Media Queries?
I'm very new to this so your patience & input is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here's a link to the page: http://buzzpunchmedia.com/bootstrap/index.html

Starts at row 98 in the html:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail-1.jpg"         alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>C Ring</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail-2.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>A Ring</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail-3.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>S Ring</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail-1.jpg"
alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>C Ring 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here's my css:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
        h1, h3, p {
        text-align: center;
    }
        .navbar-brand.brand-logo {
        display: none;
    }
    #main {
        width: 75%;
        max-width: 750px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        color: #CCCACA;
    }
    footer {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        background-color: #020202;
        color: #E5E5E5;
        text-align: center;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default {
        border-width: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .image-fill {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 0px;
        min-height: 0px;
    }
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .logobar {
        background-color: #424242;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #73A014;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .logobar-logo {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
        min-width: 100px;
        max-width: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
        max-height: 100px;
        display: block;
    }
    .logoback {
        background-color: #424242;
    }
    .bodymain {
        background-color: #424242;
    }
    #carousel1 {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

        /* Large desktops and laptops */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    }

        /* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    }

        /* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    }

        /* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .logobar-logo {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand.brand-logo {
        display: block;
    }
    .logobar {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    }

    /* Portrait phones and smaller */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .logobar-logo {
    display: none;
}
    .navbar-brand.brand-logo {
    display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, essentially all you have to do is add multiple bootstrap classes such as `.col-sm-6` (for small devices) and `.col-xs-12` (for the smallest devices) to each of your `thumbnails` and they will take up the desired sizes that you're asking for.

```
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/thumbnail-1.jpg"   class="cool-bg"      alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
             <div class="caption">
               <h3>C Ring</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
   </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/thumbnail-1.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
             <div class="caption">
               <h3>A Ring</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/thumbnail-1.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
             <div class="caption">
               <h3>S Ring</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/thumbnail-1.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Image 1" class="image-fill">
             <div class="caption">
               <h3>C Ring 2</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, tempore.</p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. That you very much. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@jmitteco` Your welcome. Bootstrap makes those gruesome `media queries` to change the `width` of the `.col-xx-xx` nice and easy for us

Comment: Wish it was easier to learn this stuff. Kinda hard to teach an old dog new tricks.
Can you recommend any resources for me to tutor myself on Bootstrap & these commands?
Thanks.

Comment: i'm a big fan of `<a href="https://www.codeschool.com/">Code School</a> `and `<a href="https://www.codecademy.com/">Code Academy</a>`. Other then that, I watch youtube tutorials and try to follow along with the videos.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check those links out.